# input value dosn't show up in angular/html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Trying to set the input value, but it wont show up. this is my form

```
<form ng-submit="editCar(indexCar);">
    Year: <input type="number" value="{{ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].year}}" ng-model="year"><br><br>
    registered: <input type="text" placeholder="{{ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].registered | date}}" ng-model="registered"><br><br>
    Make: <input type="text" placeholder="{{ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].make}}" ng-model="make"><br><br>
    Model:<input type="text" placeholder="{{ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].model}}" ng-model="model"><br><br>
    Decription:<input type="text" placeholder="{{ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].description}}" ng-model="description"><br><br>
    Price:<input type="number" value="{{ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].price}}" ng-model="price"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

number types show up, but text type dosn't appear, even though the inspector says the value is there. if i change value to placeholder it show all. is it not possible to show the text input value ?
[web inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwLDD.png)

my controller

```
  var myApp = angular.module('DemoApp', ["ngRoute"]);

    myApp.controller('CarController', [function () {
            var cars = [
                {id: 1, year: 1997, registered: new Date(1999, 3, 15), make: 'Ford', model: 'E350', description: 'ac, abs, moon', price: 3000}
                , {id: 2, year: 1999, registered: new Date(1996, 3, 12), make: 'Chevy', model: 'Venture', description: 'None', price: 4900}
                , {id: 3, year: 2000, registered: new Date(199, 12, 22), make: 'Chevy', model: 'Venture', description: '', price: 5000}
                , {id: 4, year: 1996, registered: new Date(2002, 3, 15), make: 'Jeep', model: 'Grand Cherokee', description: 'Air, moon roof, loaded', price: 4799}

            ];

            var self = this;
            self.cars = cars;
            self.title = "Cars Demo App";
            self.predicate = "year";
            self.reverse = false;
    //    self.nextId = 5;
            self.carIndex = 0;

            self.addCar = function () {
                self.newCar.id = self.cars.length + 1;
                self.cars.push(self.newCar);
                self.newCar = '';
            };

            self.deleteCar = function (car) {

                self.cars.splice(self.cars.indexOf(car), 1);
            };

    //        self.editCar = function (carIndex){
    //          
    //        };

        }]);

    myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
                .when("/", {
                    templateUrl: 'newCar.html'
                })
                .when("/edit", {
                    templateUrl: 'edit.html'
                })
    });
```

This is some part of the "main" page

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <table class="table">
        <thead >
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td><a href="" ng-click="ctrl.predicate = 'year'; ctrl.reverse=!ctrl.reverse">Year</a></td>
          <td><a href="" ng-click="ctrl.predicate = 'registered'; ctrl.reverse=!ctrl.reverse">Registered</a></td>
          <td><a href="" ng-click="ctrl.predicate = 'make'; ctrl.reverse=!ctrl.reverse">Make</a></td>
          <td><a href="" ng-click="ctrl.predicate = 'model'; ctrl.reverse=!ctrl.reverse">Model</a></td>
          <td><a href="" ng-click="ctrl.predicate = 'description'; ctrl.reverse=!ctrl.reverse">Description</a></td>
          <td><a href="" ng-click="ctrl.predicate = 'price'; ctrl.reverse=!ctrl.reverse">Price</a></td>
          <td><a>Action</a></td>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr  ng-repeat="car in ctrl.cars | filter: carfilter | orderBy:ctrl.predicate:ctrl.reverse">
          <td>{{car.id}}</td>
          <td>{{car.year }}</td>
          <td>{{car.registered | date }}</td>
          <td>{{car.make}}</td>
          <td>{{car.model}}</td>
          <td>{{car.description}}</td>
          <td>{{car.price | currency}}</td>
          <td>
            <a href="#edit" ng-click="ctrl.carIndex = ctrl.cars.indexOf(car)">edit</a> |
            <a href="#/" ng-click="ctrl.deleteCar(car)">delete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
        <a href="#/">add car</a>
      <h4>Sort Column: {{ctrl.predicate}}</h4>
      <h4>Reverse: {{ctrl.reverse}}</h4>
    </div>

    <div ng-view class="col-md-3" style="border: thin lightblue solid; border-radius: 5px;padding: 1em;"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a controller attached to that form? Also, why did you upload a screenshot of that sourcecode? Just put it directly in here...

Comment: If I understand that you want to display the value in the input then don't use value. Bind what you want displayed to ngModel. That's what will appear inside the input box.

Comment: hmm yea actually dont know why i used a screenie of the code.
i have a controller also using a route provider.

Comment: what i want to is to get the values from the object in an array and then edit the values if they are change when the form saves

Comment: You might be better off to use ng-repeat, and repeat your form for each car. Then your ng-model can bind directly to the data without needing to copy values out of your cars array into temporary variables

Comment: hmm not sure i understand that correctly, i have a tabel with repeat, and when you click at the edit link you get the specific car to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to switch the `value` and `placeholder` attributes to be `ng-model`.  `placeholder` is only used when the input is empty, so in this case you can probably just get rid of those.

Try like this:

```
<form ng-submit="editCar(indexCar);">
    Year: <input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].year"><br><br>
    registered: <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].registered" date-input><br><br>
    Make: <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].make"><br><br>
    Model:<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].model"><br><br>
    Decription:<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].description"><br><br>
    Price:<input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.cars[ctrl.carIndex].price"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

Note that where you had the `| date` filter on the registered field, I've added the `date-input` attribute - you will need to build this directive with `require: 'ngModel'` and implement `ngModel.$parsers` and `ngModel.$formatters` to process/display the date value how you want. (see [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) docs for details)

Answer (score 0):

remember to attach your controller to the HTML code using `ng-controller="nameOfController"`